# 2 squres with 1 common corner

Tags: tangent-line

The line HC is a median in triangle $\triangle BCE$

How would I prove that for two arbitrary sized squares any angle $\alpha$, $\angle DIC$ is 90 degrees?[image]

I have tried playing around with this in geogebra but to no avail.

Comment: I don't understand how a ray can be tangent to other ray. How did you pick points $H$ and $I$? Are those squares of arbitrary sizes?

Comment: ...and if you don't explain what you have tried so far, your question might end up in a shredder :)

Comment: @Oldboy Sorry for the mistakes (mistranslation). I've updated my question. Hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Choose point $J$ on line $BC$ such that $BC=CJ$. Let us focus on (green) triangle $DCG$ and (red) triangle $JCE$.

$$\angle DCG = \angle JCE = \angle JCG + 90^\circ$$

$$DC=JC,\space CG=CE$$

By SUS, triangles $DCG$ and $JCE$ are congruent and therefore $JE=DG$ and $\angle CDG = \angle CJE$. But $CD\bot CJ$ so it must be that:

$$JE\bot DG$$

(This is also obvious form the fact that triangle $JCE$ can be obtained by rotating triangle $DCG$ for $90^\circ$).

$C$ is the midpoint of $BJ$ and $H$ is the midpoint of $BE$. So lines $CH$ and $JE$ must be parallel. $JE$ is perpendicular to $DG$ and therefore $CH$ must be perpendicular too.

This also proves an interesting fact that $DG=2CH$

Comment: What a beautiful proof! I like the $90°$ triangle rotation. I found another way of proving this with the law of sines, but this one is much more eloquent.